# What is the difference between wrapping method call with addOperationWithBlock and wrapping whole method implementation with addOperationWithBlock?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

What is the difference between wrapping method call with addOperationWithBlock and wrapping whole method implementation with addOperationWithBlock?

Let's say I have a method called foo.

Is there any difference between

```
- (void) foo{
             [NSOperation mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                     some code
             }];
         }
```

AND

```
[NSOperation mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                                [self foo];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case the method foo will always be executed on the `mainQueue` (even when called from a different thread), whereas in the second case the responsibility for executing it on the right thread is delegated to whoever calls the method.

If there are situations where you might not want `foo` to execute on the main thread, then don't go for the first option. If, on the other hand, foo is *always* supposed to execute on the main thread (i.e. UI operations), the first code snippet is the way to go.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by saying "whereas in the second case the responsibility for executing it on the right thread is delegated to whoever calls the method." Since main thread should be the one who calls it, how can some other thread can call the method foo?